# Scala Types: Scala path-dependent types are compiled even expecting compile time error.

Tags: scala, types, type-systems, path-dependent-type, refinement-type

I am learning Scala type system path-dependent types and refinement types. But confused with path-dependent type scenario. My code examples of these types as below:

```
abstract class SuperHero { val team: String }

abstract class Marvel extends SuperHero

case class DrStrange(team: String) extends Marvel
case class Hulk(team: String) extends Marvel

abstract class DC extends SuperHero

case class BatMan(team: String) extends DC
case class Flash(team: String) extends DC

abstract class Tower {
    type SH <: SuperHero
    val superHero: SH
    def teamName: String = s"I am ${superHero.team}"
}

class HulkTower(val superHero: Hulk) extends Tower {
    type SH = Hulk
}

object TowerOfHero{
    def apply[F <: SuperHero](f: F) : Tower { type SH = F } = new Tower {
        override type SH = F
        override val superHero : SH = f
    }
}

val drStrangeTower = TowerOfHero(DrStrange("Avengers"))

val hulkTower : Tower { type SH = Hulk } = TowerOfHero(Hulk("Avengers"))

val hulkTower2 : HulkTower = new HulkTower(Hulk("Avengers"))
```

Below are the reference which confuse me:

```
val dtStrange5: drStrangeTower.SH = hulkTower2.superHero
```

Above code generate compile time error which is fine, because it refers to different types.

```
val hulk5: HulkTower#SH = hulkTower.superHero
val hulk6: HulkTower#SH = hulkTower2.superHero
```

Above code compile successfully which is fine, because of type projection. In type projection path of type does not depend.

```
val hulk7: hulkTower.SH = hulkTower2.superHero
```

Above code compile successfully, but I am expecting compile time error. Because of hulkTower.SH type path is different from hulkTower2.superHero type path.

Why this last snippet code is executed?

Comment: You should read [this](https://typelevel.org/blog/2015/07/13/type-members-parameters.html).

Answer (score 0):

You will need inner class for that. First, let's look at your example:

```
class HulkTower(val superHero: Hulk) extends Tower {
    type SH = Hulk
}
```

You're saying "Any `HulkTower` has the SH type defined as `Hulk`". Two `HulkTower` instances will both have the same SH type, and thus the compiler doesn't complain.

Inner class involve defining a class inside another:

```
class A {
  class B {

  }
}

val a1 = new A
val a2 = new A

val a1_b = new a1.B
val a2_b = new a2.B

val x: a1.B = a2_b // compile error
```

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/O8qE6LKBSU6tL9RytKZn5w

Note the nested `class` definition. You're essentially saying "each instance of A has their own instance of class B"

Comment: Path-dependent type can be abstract type member as well. 

`class A { type B }` 
`val a1 = new A`
`val a2 = new A`
`implicitly[a1.B =:= a2.B] // compile error`

Comment: I think you're right in the that the concept of path-dependent types subsumes both abstract type members and inner classes. I've edited my answer